# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:

Tags: mongodb, gradle, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Data MongoDB and the following are my repository + model:

```
public interface postJobRepository extends Repository<postJob,String> {
    List<postJob> findAll();
    Optional<postJob> findOne(long id);
    postJob save(postJob saved);
}
```

This is my model:

```
@Document
public final class postJob {

    @Id
    private long id;
    private  int userid;
    private String Summary;
    private String Category;
    private String SubCategory;
    private String Description;
    private String ReferenceDocs;
    private  int Budget;
    private String INR;
    private String Location;
    private String City;
    private String State;
    private String Duration;
    private String dateTimeOfPost;
    private String Status;
    private String Private;

    public int getUserid() {
        return userid;
    }
    public String getSummary() {
        return Summary;
    }
    public String getCategory() {
        return Category;
    }
    public String getSubCategory() {
        return SubCategory;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return Description;
    }
    public String getReferenceDocs() {
        return ReferenceDocs;
    }
    public int getBudget() {
        return Budget;
    }
    public String getINR() {
        return INR;
    }
    public String getLocation() {
        return Location;
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return City;
    }
    public String getState() {
        return State;
    }
    public String getDuration() {
        return Duration;
    }
    public String getDateTimeOfPost() {
        return dateTimeOfPost;
    }
    public String getStatus() {
        return Status;
    }
    public String getPrivate() {
        return Private;
    }

    public void update(int userid, String summary, String category, String   subCategory, String description,
                       String referenceDocs, int budget, String iNR, String location, String  city, String state, String duration,
                       String dateTimeOfPost, String status, String private1) {

        this.userid = userid;
        Summary = summary;
        Category = category;
        SubCategory = subCategory;
        Description = description;
        ReferenceDocs = referenceDocs;
        Budget = budget;
        INR = iNR;
        Location = location;
        City = city;
        State = state;
        Duration = duration;
        this.dateTimeOfPost = dateTimeOfPost;
        Status = status;
        Private = private1;
    }
    public postJob() {

    }
}
```

However, when I run the application I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'postJobController' defined in file [D:\Development\postJob\bin\postJob\postJobController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [postJob.postJobService]: : Error creating bean with name 'postJobServiceImp' defined in file [D:\Development\postJob\bin\postJob\postJobServiceImp.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [postJob.postJobRepository]: : Error creating bean with name 'postJobRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findOne found for type postJob!; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'postJobRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findOne found for type postJob!; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'postJobServiceImp' defined in file [D:\Development\postJob\bin\postJob\postJobServiceImp.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [postJob.postJobRepository]: : Error creating bean with name 'postJobRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findOne found for type postJob!; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'postJobRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findOne found for type postJob!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:764) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:357) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1124) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1113) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at postJob.PostJobApplication.main(PostJobApplication.java:15) [bin/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'postJobServiceImp' defined in file [D:\Development\postJob\bin\postJob\postJobServiceImp.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [postJob.postJobRepository]: : Error creating bean with name 'postJobRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findOne found for type postJob!; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'postJobRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findOne found for type postJob!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'postJobRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findOne found for type postJob!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findOne found for type postJob!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:75) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:327) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:307) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:270) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:241) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:76) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:235) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:373) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:353) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:84) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.PartTreeMongoQuery.<init>(PartTreeMongoQuery.java:54) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactory$MongoQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(MongoRepositoryFactory.java:159) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:416) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:206) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:251) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:237) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.java:108) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 44 common frames omitted

2016-01-12 12:53:10.096  INFO 7104 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/D:/Development/postJob/bin/, file:/C:/Users/shree/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.3.1.RELEASE/dd3c0e6cdee57e591eabc95a33b16233547eec91/spring-boot-starter-web-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/shree/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb/1.3.1.RELEASE/235eb4b37ab8d91f4f40cf6eec3bebe4d1907a5f/spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/shree/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test/1.3.1.RELEASE/53c089ab224613e9ae1d3f9ec58efb2a2229b152/spring-boot-starter-test-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/shree/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter/1.3.1.RELEASE/622e02ce77b3bea202b596a6fa0c40525ec81e1c/spring-boot-starter-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/shree/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.3.1.RELEASE/3c21bd7269af0df9b2d1b67581eec191e70faeb5/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/shree/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/1.3.1.RELEASE/47f424e3c7ed629b988b1976e52b662834a76856/spring-boot-starter-validation-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/shree/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.6.4/f2abadd10891512268b16a1a1a6f81890f3e2976/jackson-databind-2.6.4.jar, file:/C:/Users/shree/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-web/4.2.4.RELEASE/d4bcc6f4d8b64d7af9b67bc17f0d5106dce97926/spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/shree/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/4.2.4.RELEASE/cf4317be9c83b4c1c65ce2d3bb96673ac546030a/spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/shree/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/2.13.3/e8835850d2866528ecd45617f837c8110341ec99/mongo-java-driver-2.13.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/shree/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.data/spring-data-mongodb/1.8.2.RELEASE/b279df28ed7340c6968bee0b32b827ed1cc4ce4e/spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/shree/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/junit/junit/4.12/2973d150c0dc1fefe998f834810d68f278ea58ec/junit-4.12.jar, file:/C:/Users/shree/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/e8546f5bef4e061d8dd73895b4e8f40e3fe6effe/mockito-core-1.10.19.jar, file:/C:/Users/shree/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/42a25dc3219429f0e5d060061f71acb49bf010a0/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/shree/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-library/1.3/4785a3c21320980282f9f33d0d1264a69040538f/hamcrest-library-1.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/shree/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-core/4.2.4.RELEASE/160ccd89230753d4f49477a967f5876b034d9745/spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/shree/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-test/4.2.4.RELEASE/6efb87acf8050fc83334ffac305eb91371787283/spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/shree/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot/1.3.1.RELEASE/7ea554d1d14e180ee080abc3e7c19e316a700188/spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/shree/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.3.1.RELEASE/16ecb1f0b3ccbc8ecd52fa9de57a273d5a3eea00/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/shree/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.3.1.RELEASE/ba9d2d5094d83cf40dab474d6526befb5ce85a74/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/shree/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.yaml/snakeyaml/1.16/d64fb662c9e42789149f5078a62a22edda786c6a/snakeyaml-1.16.jar, file:/C:/Users/shree/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.30/87b12667b258d0135f7cf4234030a5ccbb55193f/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar, file:/C:/Users/shree/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.0.30/b97d5ff750126d7fdaf412aeec219306bd157e50/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.30.jar, file:/C:/Users/shree/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/8.0.30/c19b5c37e1f67bf58f9726b438d5323411cd43c6/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.30.jar, file:/C:/Users/shree/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.0.30/84cf6feff7ed4f73689b4fa076cc6ec33851e075/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar, file:/C:/Users/shree/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.2.2.Final/990905cd9184450c5f3e929ab2566305e3a67fa1/hibernate-validator-5.2.2.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/shree/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.6.4/ecbd5ad4efa46c8e88522751a80841a49e81a34d/jackson-annotations-2.6.4.jar, file:/C:/Users/shree/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.6.4/27d3a9f7bbdcf72d93c9b2da7017e39551bfa9fb/jackson-core-2.6.4.jar, file:/C:/Users/shree/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-aop/4.2.4.RELEASE/3329cf71b4bc49c9767ca4f0704ed7b773f29fba/spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/shree/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-beans/4.2.4.RELEASE/dc8e0874b53435f3e277d9da5aebd8b93cc7cf64/spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/shree/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-context/4.2.4.RELEASE/23cd0109e4eafc5629547e3680b0c4031e82efdd/spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/shree/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-expression/4.2.4.RELEASE/15b6f6d61bc68fe2cc6cbd63e2329601afb8b39/spring-expression-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/shree/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-tx/4.2.4.RELEASE/66e1a131263f5f9ba95943061b22ff2666930ca6/spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/shree/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.data/spring-data-commons/1.11.2.RELEASE/6422e6f06584244d846d6bc74e5f2c163701b89a/spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/shree/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.13/7fcf30c25b8f4a9379b9dad0d3f487b25272c026/slf4j-api-1.7.13.jar, file:/C:/Users/shree/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.13/d78d2242e14e4182625152d225f76ae52b43491d/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.13.jar, file:/C:/Users/shree/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.objenesis/objenesis/2.1/87c0ea803b69252868d09308b4618f766f135a96/objenesis-2.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/shree/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.1.3/d90276fff414f06cb375f2057f6778cd63c6082f/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/shree/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.13/43759e986de5fec7045e35e9533e5ad2f6cd1b05/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.13.jar, file:/C:/Users/shree/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.13/b5f4685073a6ffba6bf7e1d51e2b5fb83bdfa953/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.13.jar, file:/C:/Users/shree/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/8613ae82954779d518631e05daa73a6a954817d5/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/shree/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/3616bb87707910296e2c195dc016287080bba5af/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/shree/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml/classmate/1.1.0/dbbd699a1486ad0f2ed6f5af6cfed66acacb9056/classmate-1.1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/shree/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/235ba8b489512805ac13a8f9ea77a1ca5ebe3e8/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/shree/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-core/1.1.3/e3c02049f2dbbc764681b40094ecf0dcbc99b157/logback-core-1.1.3.jar]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you extend from `Repository` you have to provide two generics:

- The type of the model (`postJob`)
- The type of the ID (field with `@Id`) annotation

In your case the `@Id` annotated field is a `long`, while your repository extends from `Repository<postJob, String>`. This causes trouble, because now Spring is unable to find a `findOne()` method that has a `String` parameter.

To fix it you have to fix the generic and extend from `Repository<postJob, Long>`.

---

Please keep also in mind that fieldnames have to start with lowercase (unlike `INR`, `Budget`, `Summary`, `Location`, ...) and that class names start with a capital letter (unlike `postJob`).

I'm not sure if this will cause other issues, but some frameworks require proper field/getter/setter naming to be able to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is phrased really badly..

All i can see from the exception is that your `postJobRepository` seems to expect a PostJob to have an attribute called `findOne`. Since this obviously does not exist you get this exception.

Please provide code of PostJob and PostJobrepository for a more detailed answer

UPDATE:

change your repository to this:

```
public interface postJobRepository extends Repository<postJob,Long> {

  List<postJob> findAll();
  Optional<postJob> findOne(Long id);
  postJob save(postJob saved);
}
```

the second parameter of the Repository is the type of the id of `postJob`

Also make the id in `postJob` of type `Long` instead of `long`

One last suggestion: Classnames should start with a capital letter

Comment: have added the postjobrepository and postjob

Comment: is there a reason why your repository extends Repository instead of JpaRepository or CrudRepository?

Comment: i am providing a link .http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/creating-a-rest-api-with-spring-boot-and-mongodb/

Comment: same sample project i am trying to do

Comment: these sample project is in maven but i am using gradle

Comment: yannic can you  review my full code so that i can be good in my programming.can i send u my full code?

Comment: sure if you provide it via github. but i've not the time to do it know. I'll be home in ~ 5 hours then i can do it

Comment: don't forget to leave the link to the github repo in the comments

Comment: i have import on github check the link and please review me in detail

Comment: Forked your project and fixed your issue and a few naming conventions: https://github.com/Yannic92/spring-boot/commits/master

Comment: it  should not be converted into maven .i want in gradle only my friend

Comment: feel free to convert it to gradle again ;)

Comment: yannic i have one more issue.related to create method in postjobserviceImp class.

Comment: github link is added

Comment: when i pass the json object it stores null values in mongodb .put if i update it. works.so please check the create method in postjobserviceimp class it work with DTO.my logic is wrong please help it